# undefined class error when using inline static class functions

Tags: c++, static, inline

I have a class named CallMe that have a static method accessing a static variable...

```
// callme.h

class CallMe{

    static std::map<std::string,int> myMap;

public:

    // ... Other functions for adding removing etc...

    static int Get(std::string name)
    {
        int value = 0;
        // finding value ...
        return value;
    }
};

//  callme.cpp
std::map<std::string,int> CallMe::myMap
```

And i am using CallMe class from other class that resides in a header file user.h

// user.h

```
#include "callme.h"

class User{

public:

    int Call(std::string name)
    {
        return CallMe::Get(name);
    }
};
```

All the code are in header files(except CallMe::myMap declaration)
When I compile app. I get "undefined CallMe".

is this error happening because I defined the classes in the header files or cause of using static variable...

Comment: Please don't paraphrase an error, copy and paste into the question.

Comment: The first problem I see with your code is a missing semicolon after `std::map<std::string,int> CallMe::myMap` - but not sure (yet) if that's the *only* problem.

Comment: My crystal ball says you forgot to include the compiled callme.cpp when you are linking the final binary together.

Comment: Forgot to include the compiled callme.cpp ? Is it possible to include cpp files?

Comment: Apparently I am able to close questions without votes now. I wanted the question "does this answer your question?" to pop up when I voted to close. Oh well, if OP pastes the full error message into the question and it doesn't look like a linking error, I'll reopen.

Comment: @user3379281 Botje also wrote "_when you are linking the final binary together_". How many `.cpp` files have you created for this project? How are you compiling them? How are you linking?  What is the full error message?

Comment: @TedLyngmo You recently earned the Gold Badge for the `C++` tag! Congratulations - you now have "Thor's Hammer" for closing questions as duplicates.

Comment: @AdrianMole :-) I'll wield Mjölnir more carefully in the future.